# Yii2 :: How to change existing enum list?

Tags: mysql, enums, yii2

I have in my database enum list ('name_1','name_2','name_3'). Also I have create Model and Controller.

Later I have change enum list to ('new_name_1','new_name_2','new_name_3'). 
But in form I still see old list ('name_1','name_2','name_3').

**What must I do to refresh enum list?**

Thank you.

Comment: The whole point of using enum column types is that the data in that column should not change, ever. If it's going to be changed, say by using a form, than you should be storing that data as fields in your database.

Answer (score 1):

You should use  Alter Table Modify

```
ALTER TABLE your_db.your_table 
         MODIFY Your_enum_col ENUM('new_name_1','new_name_2','new_name_3');
```

Comment: I just started to learn Yii2... Can you tell me how can I do that?

Thank you

Comment: this is for change the values of your enum in database .. then you should execute this command  from your database ide (or console) ..otherwise  .. show your code  related to this enum ..

Answer (score 1):

Rather simple. As @scaisEdge commented, you need to execute an update query.

On a migration you can execute the following code to edit an ENUM column on Yii2.

```
 public function safeUp()
    {

        $query = "ALTER TABLE TABLENAME MODIFY tipo ENUM('VALUE1','VALUE2','VALUE4','VALUE5') default 'VALUE1'";
        $this->execute($query);
    }
```

In this case we are also giving the default value of VALUE1, in case that we don't provide a value.

Remember that you can create the migration from the console using the yii command.

```
./yii migrate/create add_enum_value_to_table
```

The migration should be on the console folder, under migrations.

Hope that it helps !